# React with mongoDb.find({}) by at least one param, but allow multiple params

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm practicing my react and mongo skills by creating a MERN reddit-like application.

I'm using mongoose.

I've successfully done passing one param, and searching based on that.

I would like to create a route that will allow a user to get results by at least one preference but allow multiple selections

Ex: Get results for "Technology", "Cooking", "Games".

My MongoDB schema contains a categories section for each post, with at least one, sometimes multiple.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9e31a445e1672d28080138"),",
    "username" : "StaySixFeetAwayPlease",
    "postTitle" : "Washer is leaking out the back.",
    "postBody" : "Hey, so last week I was doing laundry when I heard a big thud from the laundry room. Going in to investigate I couldn't figure out what caused the sound but now when I do laundry the washer leaks water. It's one of those portcullis washers with the little window in the front. Attaching a picture. Any advice?",
    "categories" : [ 
        "Appliance", 
        "Home"
    ],
    "date" : ISODate("2020-04-20T23:35:00.072Z")
}
```

How can I conditionally pass at least one OR multiple params?

And how can I get results back if at least one of the params matches in the categories array?

What I have so far.

Route

```
router.route("/cat/:category")
   .get(apiController.getPostByCategories)
```

postsController

```
      getPostByCategories: function (req, res) {

      console.log(req.params)

      db.NewPost.find({ categories: req.params.category || /req.params/i})
      .then(postCategory => {
         console.log(postCategory)
      })
      .catch(err => {
         res.status(422).json(err)
      })
   }
```

**Edit:** 
The suggested was helpful in understanding how to use the "in" regex for mongoose ([unable to use regex in $in operator in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932078/unable-to-use-regex-in-in-operator-in-mongodb)), but still unsure how to conditionally pass one or many params to search by.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to use regex in $in operator in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932078/unable-to-use-regex-in-in-operator-in-mongodb)