# Mongoose query for tags search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have some documents like this.

```
let apple = {
    id: 1,
    tags: ["red", "yellow", "fruit"],
};
let pear = {
    id: 2,
    tags: ["yellow", "brown", "fruit"],
};
let tomato = {
    id: 3,
    tags: ["red", "green", "vegetable", "small"],
};
```

I want to search items contain "re" or "fru" or "yel". Not AND.

So it should be shown all 3 items.

How to make the query?

Thanks

Comment: You can try this if it works db.fruteCollection.find( { tags: { $elemMatch: { $or:[ $regex : ".*re.*", $regex : ".*fru.*", $regex : ".*yel.*"] } } } ) . Let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to use regex in $in operator in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932078/unable-to-use-regex-in-in-operator-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the array list using regular expression and then can use `$in` operator.

```
let filter = { tags: ["re", "fru", "yel"] };
filter.tags = { $in: filter.tags.map(t => new RegExp(t)) };
console.log(filter) // { tags: { '$in': [ /re/, /fru/, /yel/ ] } }

const data = await Order.find(filter);
```